# WPF MediaElement performance

Tags: wpf, performance, animation, mediaelement

Are there any general advices on how to use MediaElement component in order not to decrease performance?

The point is, I have MediaElement with subtitles over it. And when video is playing I have bad overall performance of the application (jerks even in simple control's animations, though CPU is loaded about 20%).

I compare performance of my application with Windows Media Player, where they also have subtitiles, shadow effects and other components over the video and where everything works very smoothly.

Thanks.

Comment: could you share some code for the same. may someone can point out some issues.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that soon. Another thing I can add is that I use drop shadow effects on my subtitles and I have read that it is rather experiencive operation. But still, if you see Windows Media Player you'll see shadow effects (maybe those are different somehow)...

Comment: actually it depends on how you apply the effect, for example applying the same on a fixed rectangular surface is one time cost, but applying on a animated figure may become expensive. secondly caching the effects or even the whole element may solve some of the issues. it would be much easier to identify the actual issue after looking at your implementation. otherwise it would be just hit and trial.